# How to put unique file name for winston?

Tags: node.js, logging, mean-stack, winston

I have 10 files in which i wrote loggs for every file by putting this 2 lines in every file.

```
winston = require('winston');
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'project.log' });
```

Then i got the error

```
throw new Error('Transport already attached: ' + instance.name + ", assign a different name");
^

Error: Transport already attached: file, assign a different name
```

I want the logs of all my controllers(node.js) in only one file.Can anyone help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `filename` property on the object being passed for the new `winston.transports.File` to be unique.

For instance, if you're adding those two first lines to 10 separate files you can do something like this which will add `_${__filename}` to the name of the log file being created by winston. `__filename` is provided by the [Node Module Wrapper](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) to every single module at runtime.

```
const winston = require('winston')
winston.add(winston.transports.File, {filename: `project_${__filename}.log`})
```

If you want everything in a single file you can just create a new module that represents a Logger.

```
// logger.js
const winston = require('winston')
const logger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [ new winston.transports.File({filename: 'project.log'}) ]
})

module.exports = logger
```

Then you can require `logger.js` inside your controllers

```
// controller.js
const logger = require('./logger')

// logs "[controller.js] test-log-entry" to project.log as an info entry
logger.info(`[${__filename}] test-log-entry')
```